# Preparing data for polygon to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, rasterization

[image]

I am doing my GIS course term project in which I am integrating 3 kinds of map with index overlay method to see how much heat stress level is on my walking trail. To do it I have the tree canopy shapefile which is polygons with 100 meter distance to the trail and I should convert this vector file to raster to continue working on index overlay method.

The problem is I don't know how to rasterize the tree canopy vector file when I want to consider only the polygons which distance is not more than 10 meter to the trail.

I tried it with "Polygon to Raster" but I don't know what value field should I choose. Moreover if I add a field in the  attribute table of my tree canopy how can I specify t calculate the distance between polygons to the path line?

Comment: Perhaps review previous Q&As about rasterization using ArcGIS Desktop: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rasterization%2barcgis-desktop?tab=Votes  Are those the only fields in that feature class?  If not is there one that looks like it would be a distance?

Comment: It seems you know how to do polygon to raster, but are unclear on how to create/preserve the value needed for that transition. I'd suggest you [Edit] the question to focus on the steps before Polygon to Raster, since that's likely where the problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ArcGIS Desktop Advanced license: You can apply the *Near* tool (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) with the Canopy as input and the Path as near feature. This will calculate you the distance between your two features and add an attribute field (NEAR_DIST) to your Canopy layer with the distance for each polygon to your path (attention: the unit of the distance depends on your chosen coordinate system!).

With that you can do a simple *Select by attributes* query to select your polygons not farther away than 10 meters from your path.

For the value to use in the polygon to raster conversion it really depends on what you will need for your further analysis. You could add a new field in your attribute table and fill it with e.g. 1. Than all your rasters will have the value 1, which would be like the "Land Cover class" for your Canopy layer. Or you could now also use the distance field as the raster value, where each canopy raster cell will then have the distance to the path as a raster value.